# How do these nifty answer banners work?

Tags: support

> This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this post by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.

I saw this on an answer I downvoted recently when I went to post a comment and I was briefly confused as to where the comment button went.  Then I realized I no longer needed to comment because the banner is basically identical to the comment I would have left, minus the last sentence.

How do these banners come about?  Is this a site-specific things?  What rep do you need to add one?  How are they removed? etc.

Basically: explain this site feature to me, please.

Comment: That is known as a **post notice**, and I think only mods are able to add or remove them. If I recall correctly, we also have a tool that grabs all posts with notices, enabling us to do some cleanup long after everyone has forgotten about them. It's a feature I should probably use more often.

Comment: Even though regular users can't add them, flagging these answers as poor quality will often result in the flag being added.

Comment: It's a mod tool. If you want to use it you should run in the next election.